# Twisted Fate: Do Wildcards (Q) apply the effects of Pick A Card (W)?

Tags: league-of-legends

Wildcards (Q):

> Twisted Fate throws 3 cards forward in an arc, dealing magic damage 60 / 110 / 160 / 210 / 260 (+ 65% AP) to enemies they pass through.

Pick a Card (W):

> When first activated, cards flash over Twisted Fate's head in the following order: blue, then red, then gold (this cycle repeats itself). When he uses the ability again, he picks the current card over his head; the card picked converts his next basic attack within 6 seconds to deal magic damage and add a special effect. Twisted Fate has 6 seconds to select a card.

**Do the Wildcard cards apply the same effect as the cards in Pick a Card?**

Comment: don't get the downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The effect of Pick a Card is only applied to the next basic attack.

Answer (score 6):

His Q ability is simply an AoE spell that deals damage. Although the cards do occasionally change their color, there is no additional effect to it. It's just cosmetic.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work with his Q ability.